# Laravel 7 deploy in shared hosting (hostgator) Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, shared-hosting, laravel-7

I am trying to deploy my Laravel app in a shared hosting (hostgator).

- I have upgraded php version to 7.3 and it shows when tested with
  phpinfo().
- Also I have created an index.html file on the root to
  test whether the .htaccess working or not and it worked.
- I have removed the files under cache folder inside bootstrap folder.
- I checked my .env file whether it has any mis-configuration or not.
- I have given 777 permission to bootstrap and storage folder

my .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
    
    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_flag display_startup_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 256M
   php_value post_max_size 260M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 256M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
   php_flag display_errors On
   php_flag display_startup_errors On
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 256M
   php_value post_max_size 260M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 256M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

In my error.log file I am having:

```
[21-Jul-2020 11:29:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ixed.7.1.lin' (tried: /opt/php71/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/ixed.7.1.lin (/opt/php71/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/ixed.7.1.lin: undefined symbol: _zval_ptr_dtor), /opt/php71/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/ixed.7.1.lin.so (/opt/php71/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/ixed.7.1.lin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
[21-Jul-2020 06:29:33 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist in /home2/courage/www.mysite.xyz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:805
Stack trace:
#0 /home2/courage/www.mysite.xyz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(805): ReflectionClass->__construct('config')
#1 /home2/courage/www.mysite.xyz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(687): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('config')
#2 /home2/courage/www.mysite.xyz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(796): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('config', Array, true)
#3 /home2/courage/www.mysite.xyz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(633): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('config', Array)
#4 /home2/courage/www.mysite.xyz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(781): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('config', Array)
#5 /home2/courage/www.mysite.xyz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/C in /home2/courage/www.mysite.xyz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 807
```

and I am getting the following error when load site in browser:

**`Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist in /home2/courage/www.mysite.xyz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:805 Stack trace: #0 /home2/courage/www.mysite.xyz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(805): ReflectionClass->__construct('config') #1 /home2/courage/www.mysite.xyz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(687): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('config') #2 /home2/courage/www.mysite.xyz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(796): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('config', Array, true) #3 /home2/courage/www.mysite.xyz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(633): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('config', Array) #4 /home2/courage/www.mysite.xyz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(781): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('config', Array) #5 /home2/courage/www.mysite.xyz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/C in /home2/courage/www.mysite.xyz/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 807`**

Comment: Maybe this can help you? https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/192#issuecomment-240915060

Comment: I dont use this package @OlegNurutdinov

Comment: There is not about this package. There is about packages in general. Also this issue has another solutions which can help.

Comment: ```<?php

$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Http\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

return $app;```

my app.php inside bootstrap folder.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, solved by contacting with hosting co. It was their upgrade issue.

Comment: Hello @WahidSherief can you tell me, what was the solution give by hosting team?
I am facing same issue. I think its hostgator's server issue.